# Error while calling apex_web_service - "Table or view doesn't exist"

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-18.2, oracle-apex-plugin

I am getting an intermittent errror while calling apex_web_service. Normally it works fine but sometimes suddenly it gives "No table or View exists error", without any code change.

I have to click a button to call this webservice. And when I get this error and click on the same button again, the error goes away and everything works fine. So this is really an intermittent issue which suddenly pops up and goes away by clicking the button again.

Can somebody help me understand why this could be ocurring.

Regards,
Abha

Comment: Have you tried restarting ORDS? I don't know about JDBC, but I've seen "statement caches" elsewhere cause similar issues. If you restart ORDS and don't make and DDL changes to your environment, you could at least rule that out.

Answer (score 0):

You should restart ORDS to fix this intermittent issue. You might want to upgrade to the latest ORDS if possible. Also, please make sure your browser cache is deleted and restart your browser.